# MYSQL Rounding issue

Tags: mysql, rounding, rounding-error

WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?

```
SELECT 
c.tax_rate, 
c.line_item_total_price, 
c.shipping_total_price, 
ROUND((c.tax_rate * 
(c.line_item_total_price+c.shipping_total_price)),2), 
(c.tax_rate * (c.line_item_total_price+c.shipping_total_price)) 
FROM carts c
WHERE c.id = 323002;
```

returns:

```
.07
925.00
62.50
69.12
69.125
```

But this:

```
SELECT 
ROUND((.07 * (925.00+62.50)),2), 
(.07 * (925.00+62.50));
```

Returns the correct:

```
69.13
69.1250
```

Why the extra 0 at the end of that one?

FYI: Shipping and line item are DECIMAL(10,2) and tax is DOUBLE

Comment: I don't know a lot about MySQL but I would guess that it's an implicit conversion thing based on the column types. Maybe try casting everything until you find out what one was giving you the problem.  DECIMAL(10,2) only allows 2 decimal places (thats what the 2 is)

Comment: If that were the case, then wouldn't it be 69.12 for the non-rounded one in the first query as well? Why would it round to 3 places vs having the 0 at the end like the second query? It's very strange to me.

Comment: Like I said, I am far from an expert in MySql but my guess would be that in your direct select MySql is implicitly assigning data types to your hard-coded values and that it has a precision of 3

Comment: Ok, I'll try a few things. At least you gave me something new to test. Thanks.

Comment: This worked: ROUND(CAST(c.tax_rate * (c.line_item_total_price+c.shipping_total_price) as DECIMAL(10,3)),2)

Comment: Post your comment as an answer with my example and I'll mark as the solution

Comment: Why did you define `tax_rate` as `float`? It should be DECIMAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about MySQL but I would guess that it's an implicit conversion thing based on the column types. Maybe try casting everything until you find out what one was giving you the problem. DECIMAL(10,2) only allows 2 decimal places (that's what the 2 is)

Comment: worked: ROUND(CAST(c.tax_rate * (c.line_item_total_price+c.shipping_total_price) as DECIMAL(10,3)),2)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 1.00 * 1.0
```

You will get `1.000`. This is because the exact result for `DECIMAL(a,b) * DECIMAL(c,d)` needs a `DECIMAL(a+c,b+d)` as data type.